# Connection String Error. Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-connection

In my first MVC 4 application, I encounter following error in the code.

```cs
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("fousuEntities", "usertable", "UserID", "UserCode", autoCreateTables: true);
```

In my config file I do have following entries,

```xml
<add name="fousuEntities"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/fousutable.csdl|res://*/fousutable.ssdl|res://*/fousutable.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;User Id=user;password=pwd;database=fousutable&quot;" />
```

Please help me what I missed in this code?

- Visual Studio 2010 SP1
- MVC 4
- Trying to use simplemembership provider
- Installed Entity Framework 5.0
- .Net FrameWork 4.0
- Database MySQL 5.1

#### UPDATE 1:

> Error Details :
>
> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
>
> ```cs
>                      using (var context = new UsersContext())
>                      {
>                          if (!context.Database.Exists())
>                          {
>                              // Create the SimpleMembership database without      Entity Framework migration schema
> ```

#### UPDATE 2:

Well I was able to get rid off the above error by changing the entries in *web.config* as follows, though end up getting another error.

```xml
<add name="fousuEntities"
     connectionString="Server=MySQL; Database=fousutable; uid=user; pwd=pwd;"
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

And added one more entry under `System.Data`,

```xml
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=5.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Now the new error I got was **Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.** for the `LazyInitializer` line:

```cs
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
            LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
        }
```

After referring to the details of `InnerException`, I got something like **"The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized."**

Comment: @Drewman sorry added error details!!

Comment: @Drewman thanks I got solved that issue with following code change in web.config, Edited as UPDATE 2 , However got another error, please refer the edited version

Comment: Where do you invoke your WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(...)

Comment: In the same file under Filters, InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs where I get the error. I also has the class SimpleMembershipInitializer where I call  WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("fousuEntities", "usertable", "UserID", "UserCode", autoCreateTables: true); . By the way I am using a MySQL database, Which we manually created.

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of your connection string. Most probably you have changed from "DefaultConnection" to any other value and sure you have changed it properly in the SimpleMembershipInitializer in the line

> WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyNewConnectionString", "Users", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

But you have to be aware that in your AccountModels.cs file you have a UsersContext and you have to update that in the constructor:

> ```
>     public UsersContext() : base("MyNewConnectionString")
>     {
>     }
> ```

Otherwise it will continue to try to find "DefaultConnection" which doesn´t exist. That could be the reason why it fails.